# Nativescript build for ios succeeds but getting error message

Tags: nativescript

Building my app for a device and it seems to succeed but comes back with no .ipa file found - but it's there.

```
** EXPORT SUCCEEDED **

Project successfully built.
No .ipa found in /Users/mini/Projects/publish-app-ios/platforms/ios/build/Release-iphoneos directory.
```

the above is a result of a `tns build ios --for-device ...` command.

My xcode version is 12.5.1 and I would prefer not to update.

I'm using NS 6 and have added the fixes on [How to Fix NativeScript Issue with iOS14 and XCode 12](https://timleland.com/how-to-fix-nativescript-issue-with-ios14-and-xcode-12/)

Answer (score 0):

**tns run ios** works ok?
which version tns-ios using in package.json?
try to set

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "package.name",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.5.3"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.4"
    }
  },
...
}
```

if it was set different version, run **tns platform remove ios** before **tns run**

Or do you run **tns build** for publication?

Comment: Yes I have ios 6.5.4 and CLI 6.7.8 (seems to be the latest 6.*) Builds for simulator ok - it's when I build for device - that I have the problem.